# Convert Document.getFileAsync data to FormData for Office file uploading

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office, office-js, excel-addins, word-addins

I'm working on Office Add-in project, I need to get current Office file and upload to our server.
Below is upload file from File Browser to our server

```
var fdata = new FormData();
fdata.append('data', file);
fdata.append('totalFileSizeBytes', file.size);
fdata.boundary = '----boundary';

xhr.send(fdata);
```

And I got Office file info via function: Document.getFileAsync (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync)

But I don't know how to convert File info from Document.getFileAsync to FormData.
I tried read File info slice by slice then concat to an array and pass to FormData, but it wasn't success.

Comment: @CindyMeister I’m working on Office JS API

Comment: I've added that tag so that the right people are more likely to see your question.

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word#add-the-javascript-to-get-the-document

Answer (score 6):

The answer is a bit late, but hopefully might help future folks looking for this - I wasted some time trying to figure this out.

The File object returned by the `Document.getFileAsync` is not usable with FormData. Also what the Microsoft Documentation shows you does not get you a file that you can just drop into FormData.

First, you'll have to combine the slices returned to a `docdata` array as per the Microsoft example shows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=office-js#getfileasync-filetype--options--callback-). But then instead of creating a string out of it by using `charCodeAt`, you'll want just use the combined `docdata` array and do this:

```js
const file = new File(
  [new Uint8Array(docdata)], 
  'testfile.docx', 
  { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' }
);
```

Which you can then proceed to append to your FormData:

```js
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);
```

Answer (score 2):

The new File() gave me an error. But the a new Blob() did the trick

```
var aFile = new Blob(
    [new Uint8Array(docdata)],
    { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' }
);

formData.append('file', aFile, 'testfile.docx');
```